# Pedir un objeto de arreglo

Tags: java

```java
public void crear_profesor(Profesor profesor[]){

        profesor[0]=new Profesor("Matematica","Paul",34,'m',"Jhonson");
        profesor[1]=new Profesor("Fisica","Cue",29,'f',"Seele");
        profesor[2]=new Profesor("Filosofia","Chabashira",28,'f',"Youkoso");
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void profesor_materia(Profesor profesor[]){

        String materia[]={"Matematica","Fisica","Filosofia","Quimica","Ingles","Lengua"};
        int aleatorio=(int)(Math.random()*6);
        String m="";
        String n="";
        String a="";
        String m2="";
        String n2="";
        String a2="";
        boolean mat=false;

        for (int i=0;i<profesor.length;i++){
            if (materia[aleatorio].equals(profesor[i].getMateria())){
                mat=true;
                m=profesor[i].getMateria();
                n=profesor[i].getNombre();
                a=profesor[i].getApellido();
                break;
            }else{
                mat=false;
                m2=profesor[i].getMateria();
                n2=profesor[i].getNombre();
                a2=profesor[i].getApellido();
            }
        }

        if (mat==true){
            System.out.println("Profesor: "+n+" "+a+", dara clases de: "+m);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Profesor: "+n2+" "+a2+", no dara clases de: "+m2);
        }
}
```

Lo que quiero realizar con este método es lo siguiente:
creé un arreglo de materias y lo hice de manera aleatoria con las materias de los profesores.

Pregunto si la materia aleatoria que toque es igual a la materia de un profesor, si es igual que muestre su nombre y apellido y el nombre de su materia, caso contrario, mostrará que ese profesor no puede dar clases de una materia que no es su materia a enseñar.

los errores que tengo son que un profesor enseña **fisica** y a la vez me toca que ese mismo profesor no puede dar clase porque no es su materia cuando sí lo es.

Otro error que tengo es que las materias **quimica, ingles, lengua** no me tocan, solo me tocan de manera aleatoria las 3 primeras.

Esto después lo ejecuto en la clase main, pero esos son los métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Debes analizar un poco tu codigo,estas creando solo 3 profesores..

```
profesor[0]=new Profesor("Matematica","Paul",34,'m',"Jhonson");
profesor[1]=new Profesor("Fisica","Cue",29,'f',"Seele");
profesor[2]=new Profesor("Filosofia","Chabashira",28,'f',"Youkoso");
```

y 6 materias

```
String materia[]={"Matematica","Fisica","Filosofia","Quimica","Ingles","Lengua"};
```

que pasa cuando la materia aleatoria es `lengua`(tomando como ejemplo),pues ninguno de tus profesores enseña lengua.tu ciclo `for`,ira consultando si el primer profesor enseña lengua(no), el segundo(no) y el tercero(no),entonces al no cumplirse el `if` pasara al `else`: mostrando los datos del ultimo profesor en el arreglo `chabashira` y aunque este enseñe `Filosofia` saldra que no ,pues es lo que tu estas imprimiendo en el else

```
for (int i=0;i<profesor.length;i++){
            if (materia[aleatorio].equals(profesor[i].getMateria())){
                mat=true;
                m=profesor[i].getMateria();
                n=profesor[i].getNombre();
                a=profesor[i].getApellido();
                break;
            }else{
                mat=false;
                m2=profesor[i].getMateria();
                n2=profesor[i].getNombre();
                a2=profesor[i].getApellido();
            }
        }
```

aunque crees 6 profesores con 6 materias y uses el mismo codigo siempre caera en el `if` ,creo que por eso creaste 3 profesores,de querer plasmar el ejercicio te sugiero que tanto la materia como el profesor sean elegidos aleatoriamente de esa manera si coiciden dara los datos esperados de no coincidir bueno saldra que el curso aleatorio no corresponde al profesor aleatorio ;)